# Joomla pretty link to article

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, module, pretty-urls

I want to create a button with a link to an article for which I have the ID. I get the ID from a form field which returns a menu item ID. So far I've tried this:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&id=280"><p>read it</p></a>
```

result = `/joomla/index.php?id=69`, so it doesn't work.

The end result should be something like this:

```
/joomla/index.php/using-joomla 

/joomla/index.php/using-joomla/extensions
```

Comment: I added an apparently relevant tag and rephrased the title per the last examples, and fixed the grammar and some formatting in the rest to make it more understandable.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you could use edit summary field to add comments about your edit.

Comment: @emmanuel: So I could, and did. [H&I](http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/) mean anything to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new menu item for this article and use the alias field to add the desired url value. The menu could also be hidden and used only for sef url creation.

Hope this helps.